# How many database connections from a pool are occupied during one EJB transaction?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I would like to know how many database connections from my database pool are occupied during the call of the following example code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class SomeDbBean {

    @Resource(name = "jdbc/mydatabase")
    private DataSource database;

    public void updateSomeValues() throws SQLException, InterruptedException {

        // Connection 1, normally this is done in another method
        try (Connection conn = database.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("update some where id = 1")) {
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }

        // Sleep to mimic some long processing logic
        Thread.sleep(30000);

        // Connection 2, normally this is done in another method
        try (Connection conn = database.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("update some where id = 2")) {
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

The database commits happen once the method finishes, but what would be done with the two database connections I received from my connection pool? The try with resources call close on the connections. Will the connections remain occupied until the transaction is completed? Or are they freed to the database connection pool and JEE handles the commit in an invisible way?

When I have a connection pool with 50 connections can I call this method 50 times without a problem, or can I call this method 25 times before the pool runs out of connections?

NOTE: I do not configure the JEE application server to use 'Pinned-To-Thread' or 'associate-with-thread' application server specific database connection pool settings.

I cannot really find the answer when looking at

- https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/Specifications
- https://github.com/javaee/jta-spec
- https://github.com/javaee/jta-spec/blob/master/JTA1.3Specification.pdf

I come as close as: *how an application server may handle
a connection request from the application*

> 8. The application server invokes the getConnection method.
> 9. The application server returns the Connection object reference to the application.
> 10. The application performs one or more operations on the connection.
> 11. The application closes the connection.
> 12. The application server delists the resource when notified by the resource adapter about the connection close.
> 13. The transaction manager invokes XAResource.end to disassociate the transaction from the XAResource.
> 14. The application server asks the transaction manager to commit the transaction.
> 15. The transaction manager invokes XAResource.prepare to inform the resource manager to prepare the transaction work for commit.
> 16. The transaction manager invokes XAResource.commit to commit the transaction.

Which seems to suggest Connection1 is given back to the resource pool to be reused before the EJB transaction is committed.